# перевести формат времени из 12 часов в 24 часа

Tags: java, дата, simpledateformat

```
Date maxDate = new Date(); //сейчас эта дата в формате 12 часов, а мне нужно перевести в формат 24 часа.

  return airport.getTerminals().stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getFlights().stream())
            .filter(x -> x.getDate().getHours() < maxDate.getHours()+2
                    && x.getDate().getHours() >= maxDate.getHours()
                    && x.getDate().getDay() == maxDate.getDay()
                    && x.getDate().getMonth() == maxDate.getMonth()
                    && x.getDate().getYear() == maxDate.getYear())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: А locale использовать нельзя?

Comment: почему вы не используете LocalDateTime ?